# How to set Response.Cache.SetCacheability in ASP.net WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, caching, webforms, browser-cache

How do i call `Response.Cache.SetCacheability` in WebForms?

If you look at MSDN's [**How to: Set a Page's Cacheability Programmatically**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z852zf6b(v=vs.90).aspx):

> **To set a page's cacheability programmatically**
>
> - In the page's code, call the [SetCacheability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.setcacheability(v=vs.90).aspx) method on the [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cache(v=vs.90).aspx) property of the [Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.response(v=vs.90).aspx) object.
>
>   The following code sets the **Cache-Control** HTTP header to [Public](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcacheability(v=vs.90).aspx).
>
>   ```
>   Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
>   ```

Fine. Excellent. Good. Except how do i do it?

In try adding it to the **Page_Init** event handler:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public); //Public, while we test this
}
```

But the response from the server does is not public (and in fact is **private**):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
Date: Fri, 11 Jul 2014 14:11:06 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 9382
Connection: Close
```

So i want to confirm that my code is working, so i add some dummy headers:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Response.Headers.Add("X-Hello-Before", "WhyArentYouWorking");
    Response.AddHeader("X-Hello-Before", "WhyArentYouWorking");

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public); //Client is allowed to cache

    //Response.Headers.Add("X-Hello-After", "MyGodYouSuck");
    Response.AddHeader("X-Hello-After", "MyGodYouSuck");
}
```

and the items appear in the response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
Date: Fri, 11 Jul 2014 14:16:47 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Hello-Before: WhyArentYouWorking
X-Hello-After: MyGodYouSuck
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 9382
Connection: Close
```

The question is:

> How do i make ASP.net do what i tell it to do?

I don't know where the bug is. It could be in ASP.net. It could be in WebForms. It could be in .NET Framework 4.0. It could be in Cassini.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a proxy in between, maybe that is not letting you change it?  Otherwise you can try to set it IIS as well:

1. Open your IIS Manager, go to your application in the tree.
2. Select your application and in the right hand section Double click "HTTP Respond Headers" option.
3. Click "Add…" on the Actions Panel

Fill in the pop-up window:
Name: Cache-Control
Value: public

and see if that works.